# Calculate current through a resistor attached to an ADC?

Tags: current, adc, resistance, dac, ohms-law

I have a resistor, R1 = 100 kΩ, connected between a:

- DAC PIN_1 outputting 1.34 V
- ADC PIN_2

At PIN_2 I measure 0.57 V.

1. Can i model the circuit as:PIN_1 -- 100 kΩ R1 -- PIN_2 -- R_ADC -- GND?

- For V1 = 1.34 V we have ΔV= 1.34-0.57

**I want to calculate ΔV if V1=1.8 V**

If i coudl use the cirucit above, i could calculate R_ADC=0.57/I and find out what Δ would be with V1=1.8 V.

To calculate *I* through the resistor, I just did

2. ΔV / R1 = (1.34 - 0.57) / 100e3 = 7.7e-06  is this correct?

However, if I connect a current to digital converter on PIN_2, and measure current, I get: I = 1.8e-7 A.

2. Why is the calculated current (ΔV / R) different from measured current with current to digital converter?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMfTdx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**EDIT: Explaing my problem in more detail**

What i am trying to do is use NHS3152 to caculate the resitance of my DUT. I am running some tests now.
The way NXP (the chip manufactures) say to do it is:
Give fixed Voltage output at PIN_1

1. Find V at PIN_1
2. Find V at PIN_2
3. Find I at PIN_2
4. R= (V(PIN_1)-V(PIN_2))/I

What is unclear to me is why when i test it wiht R1 = 100 kΩ, i calculate:

ΔV / R1 = (1.34 - 0.57) / 100e3 = 7.7e-06

but measure:

I = 1.8e-7

This here is the Datasheet of my device: [DATASHEET 3152 PG34](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NHS3152.pdf)[image: I2D NHS3152 DATASHEET]

Comment: Current is **through** the resistor, not over the resistor.

Comment: I fixed it and a couple of details.

Comment: @leo, what does "*What should I model the ADC --> GND as?*" mean?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. As far as I can tell, the answers are: 1) no answer. What is the scope of the question? Do you know what an ADC is or how it works? 2) yes, Ohm's law applies to a voltage drop through a resistor; 2) It is possible that by adding a sensor, you are changing the loading of the circuit and therefore the current. Are you aware of how your sensor works, or how non-ideal voltage sources can be modeled as an ideal voltage source with a series resistor? This could explain the disparity.

Comment: @Transistor I wanted to see if i can think of the circuit as PIN_1 -- 100 kΩ R1 -- PIN_2 -- R_ADC -- GND. I thought this could be the case to explain why PIN_2 =0.57 V and not 0 V.

Comment: ADC pin is not ground. The most accurate way to measure current through the resistor is to directly measure the voltage across it, and divide by 100K. This is better than measuring each side to ground because adding the multimeter load to ground can affect the voltage reading in very high impedance circuits (probably not a problem here). Your current measurement is different, I suspect, merely because most multimeters can't measure sub uA levels accurately.

Comment: @td127 "voltage reading in very high impedance circuits" my actual device has a resitance between 1-10 MΩ is this considered a "very high impedance circuit" ?

Comment: @td127"Your current measurement is different, I suspect, merely because most multimeters can't measure sub uA levels accurately" - Ok, so it is a probelm with the devices accuracy

Comment: A typical multimeter will have on the order of 10MΩ across its leads when measuring voltage. So the 10M across your 100K will make it behave like a 99K resistor - not too bad, and you can adjust your current calculation accordingly. But if your circuit impedances are up in the megΩ range then the meter will increasingly affect the reading. But I think it's your current measurement that is more suspect, just because it's so tiny.